# asp.net code behind does not redirect when using jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net, http, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page that uses a dialog page to perform an action. When the buttons are clicked I execute the code in my code behind which works perfectly however, I need to redirect or close the dialog page which for some reason it is not working. Here is my code for the dialog page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div data-role="header" role="banner">
            <h1 role="heading">Claim Issue?</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-c" role="main">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="CompanyLBL">Company:</label>
                <asp:Label ID="CompanLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="IssueLBL">Issue:</label>
                <asp:Label ID="IssueLBL" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="FBVersionLBL">Version:</label>
                <asp:Label ID="FBVersionLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div data-role="button">
            <asp:Button ID="ClaimBTN" runat="server" Text="Yes" onclick="ClaimBTN_Click" />
            </div>
            <a href="./Queue.aspx" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span></span></a>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
//Claim Issue
protected void ClaimBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Tier2IssuesSDS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Tier2Issues SET Tier2ID = @Tier2ID, IssueStatusID = @IssueStatusID, DateLastModified = @DateLastModified, UserLastModified = @UserLastModified WHERE ID = @ID";
        Tier2IssuesSDS.UpdateParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["IssueID"].ToString();
        Tier2IssuesSDS.UpdateParameters["Tier2ID"].DefaultValue = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        Tier2IssuesSDS.UpdateParameters["IssueStatusID"].DefaultValue = "2";
        Tier2IssuesSDS.UpdateParameters["DateLastModified"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Tier2IssuesSDS.UpdateParameters["UserLastModified"].DefaultValue = Session["Username"].ToString();
        Tier2IssuesSDS.Update();

        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Tier 2/Admin/Mobile/Queue.aspx");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Tier 2/Admin/Mobile/Queue.aspx");
    }
}
```

What am I missing or what is the work around to get this thing to close the dialog or successfully redirect the browser to the starting page?

Comment: Add `data-ajax="false"` to button.

Comment: Instead of response.redirect could you use registerclientscript (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy(v=vs.110).aspx) to send back javascript that closes the dialog?

Comment: data-ajax doesn't work

Comment: @ezanker Would I do that on the dialog page or the main page?

Comment: in your ClaimBtn_click handler instead of response.redirect, send a javascript block that navigates to the desired page (e.g. $.mobile.navigate( "Queue.aspx" );)

Comment: I tried that and still no go.